# Gitlab: How to modify file before merge to master

Tags: gitlab, cicd

Using GitLab is there a hook that will allow me to run a script to modify a file inside of my repository before/during a merge operation?

I have a pre-commit hook that modifies a file accordingly for my CI/CD pipeline to succeed. If the test pipelines succeed, then I need to modify that same file again before merging changes into the master branch.

Is there a GitLab hook that will allow me to do this?

Comment: Couldn't you do this with a job following the test job in the pipeline?

Comment: I can't see how you could change a file already in the repository after test but before merge.

Comment: Sorry i misunderstood you. I thought you want to change a file directly after the merge and not between the test-job and the merge itself. The only possible solution could be [a merge result pipeline](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/merged_results_pipelines.html). But this comes only with GitLab-premium or higher.